# Keras model.get_config() returns list instead of dictionary

Tags: tensorflow, keras, typeerror

I am using tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0 and keras from tensorflow as tf.keras.
I am trying to use source code written by someone else to implement it on my network.

I saved my network using save_model and load it using load_model. when I use model.get_config(), I expect a dictionary, but i"m getting a list. Keras source documentation also says that get_config returns a dictionary (https://keras.io/models/about-keras-models/).

I tried to check if it has to do with saving type : save_model or model.save that makes the difference in how it is saved, but both give me this error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

my code block :

```py
        model_config = self.keras_model.get_config()
        for layer in model_config['layers']:
            name = layer['name']
            if name in update_layers:
                layer['config']['filters'] = update_layers[name]['filters']
```

my pip freeze :

```
absl-py==0.6.1
astor==0.7.1
bitstring==3.1.5
coverage==4.5.1
cycler==0.10.0
decorator==4.3.0
Django==2.1.3
easydict==1.7
enum34==1.1.6
futures==3.1.1
gast==0.2.0
geopy==1.11.0
grpcio==1.16.1
h5py==2.7.1
image==1.5.15
ImageHash==3.7
imageio==2.5.0
imgaug==0.2.5
Keras==2.1.3
kiwisolver==1.1.0
lxml==4.1.1
Markdown==3.0.1
matplotlib==2.1.0
networkx==2.2
nose==1.3.7
numpy==1.14.1
olefile==0.46
opencv-python==3.3.0.10
pandas==0.20.3
Pillow==4.2.1
prometheus-client==0.4.2
protobuf==3.6.1
pyparsing==2.3.0
pyquaternion==0.9.2
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.7
PyWavelets==1.0.1
PyYAML==3.12
Rtree==0.8.3
scikit-image==0.13.1
scikit-learn==0.19.1
scipy==0.19.1
Shapely==1.6.4.post1
six==1.11.0
sk-video==1.1.8
sklearn-porter==0.6.2
tensorboard==1.10.0
tensorflow-gpu==1.10.0
termcolor==1.1.0
tqdm==4.19.4
utm==0.4.2
vtk==8.1.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
xlrd==1.1.0
xmltodict==0.11.0
```

Comment: keras and tf.keras are not the same, there are incompatibilities like what you just found.

Comment: I think this is the duplicate of https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11179, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9783, and https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11133. Basically, it was a BUG in the previous versions. Hence my suggestion is updating Tensorflow and Keras might solve your issue. I didn't reproduce your issue but I think updating will solve your issue. Read https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/11133.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this worked. I principally didn't want to do an upgrade because I am trying to reproduce some results and many other lines of code depend on the older version. I upgraded tf to 1.11.0 and tweaked other lines of code to get it running.